# I'm trying to simply append two different data types into my xml file and read them again, but I am getting an error

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, filestream, streamwriter

I'm using Winforms and I get the following error when I press the load button after having hit the save button:

> InvalidOperationException:  was not expected.

Here is my code:

```
private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if you don't specify it, then it saves in the bin folder of the program
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Student2.Xml", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write); //@"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Student.Xml"

    StudentClass sc = new StudentClass();

    sc.Name = textBox1.Text;
    sc.Class = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

    ls.Add(sc);
       
    StudentSerializer.Serialize(fs, ls);
    DicSerializer.Serialize(fs,
                            dict.Select(kv => new DicItem() { id = kv.Key, value = kv.Value }).ToArray());

    fs.Close();
}

private void load_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Student2.Xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    ls = (List<StudentClass>)StudentSerializer.Deserialize(fs);

    var orgDict = ((DicItem[])DicSerializer.Deserialize(fs))
                     .ToDictionary(i => i.id, i => i.value);

    foreach (var item in orgDict) 
         Debug.WriteLine(item.Key + " and " + item.Value);

    fs.Close();
}
```

My dictionary already has two items in it. And my student class has two items as well from the textboxes. Also note, my xml file gets wiped clean after that error. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Also, this is what my xml looks like right after hitting the save button:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfStudentClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <StudentClass>
    <Name>wewewe</Name>
    <Class>2222</Class>
  </StudentClass>
</ArrayOfStudentClass><?xml version="1.0"?>
<DicItem xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <DicItem id="1" value="one" />
  <DicItem id="2" value="two" />
</DicItem>
```

Comment: An XML file can have only a single root element. Therefore, concatenating two XML files results in a file that is not valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

The complaint is because of `<?xml version="1.0"?>` right before the first DictItem tag. Such tag AFAIK should appear once only in the XML file.

You should post the Deserializer code for each class for more investigation.

Comment: how to i only add it once then or how do i remove it?

Comment: It's not only the duplicate XML declaration, but also - and more important - the presence of two root elements.

Comment: Mmmmh, then create a single root element by serializing an array containing your first and second element.

Comment: Implement the ISerializable interface for each class.

Answer (score -2):

If you remove the second declaration than following code will work

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME, settings);

            reader.ReadToFollowing("ArrayOfStudentClass");
            XElement ArrayOfStudentClass = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);

            reader.ReadToFollowing("DicItem");
            XElement DicItem = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);

        }
    }
}
```